When using HttpHeaderAuth, the findIdentityByAccessToken method is not called
Yii2
When i put var_dump in findIdentityByAccessToken method is not called
Why is findIdentityByAccessToken method not called?
Why is there no user verification?
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer tok" -H "Accept: application/json" https://....plcapp/cooper/listcontr
I get error 403.
<?php

namespace common\modules\plcapp\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;
use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
//use yii\rest\ActiveController;
use yii\web\Controller;
//use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
//use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use common\models\Access;
use common\models\DevContr;
use common\models\User;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class CooperController extends Controller
{
    //public $modelClass = 'common\models\User';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => HttpBearerAuth::class,
        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }


    public function actionConect()
    {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionListcontr()
    {

        Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;

            return [
                'success' => true,
            ];

    }
}

LGpt4 chat can't say anything useful

I can't say where exactly is AccessControl filter applied from your code. You need to make sure HttpBearerAuth behavior is applied before AccessControl filter. Otherwise access is denied before attempting authentication. If they are both set up in behaviors() method of controller then their order in array decide the execution order.
